# grub: unknown file system when change partitions in Windows

Tags: grub2, 18.04, boot-repair

I have strange problem from last days. In past I create my Ubuntu deleting drive G: in Windows 10 (450 GB). Create Ubuntu partitions on 150 GB, so i have 300 GB free unused space. Today I need some space in Windows, so create again drive G: with unused free space (300 GB). When I restarting my PC, and set boot from HDD (my windows boot from SSD) get the unknown file system error.

I have checked ubuntu partitions end they are still there, but can't boot or repair Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: Boot to a LiveUSB, and show `sudo fdisk -l` output.  Also include a screenshot of Windows' disk manager so we can see what Windows sees.

Comment: Here is the fdisk - https://pastebin.com/WUXMcU5G
The screenshot is - https://imgur.com/a/yHx9KNm